# Создать словарь со словарями из txt файла

Tags: python, словари, txt

Есть текстовый файл с рецептами, например:

> **Омлет**
> 3 # показывает кол-во ингредиентов в блюде
> Яйцо | 2 | шт
> Молоко | 100 | мл
> Помидор | 2 | шт
> **Утка по-пекински**
> 4
> Утка | 1 | шт
> Вода | 2 | л
> Мед | 3 | ст.л
> Соевый соус | 60 | мл
> **Запеченный картофель**
> 3
> Картофель | 1 | кг
> Чеснок | 3 | зубч
> Сыр гауда | 100 | г
> **Фахитос**
> 5
> Говядина | 500 | г
> Перец сладкий | 1 | шт
> Лаваш | 2 | шт
> Винный уксус | 1 | ст.л
> Помидор | 2 | шт

Из этого нужно сделать словарь со словарями такого вида:

```
cook_book = {
  'Омлет': [
    {'ingredient_name': 'Яйцо', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'шт.'},
    {'ingredient_name': 'Молоко', 'quantity': 100, 'measure': 'мл'},
    {'ingredient_name': 'Помидор', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'шт'}
    ],
  'Утка по-пекински': [
    {'ingredient_name': 'Утка', 'quantity': 1, 'measure': 'шт'},
    {'ingredient_name': 'Вода', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'л'},
    {'ingredient_name': 'Мед', 'quantity': 3, 'measure': 'ст.л'},
    {'ingredient_name': 'Соевый соус', 'quantity': 60, 'measure': 'мл'}
    ],
  'Запеченный картофель': [
    {'ingredient_name': 'Картофель', 'quantity': 1, 'measure': 'кг'},
    {'ingredient_name': 'Чеснок', 'quantity': 3, 'measure': 'зубч'},
    {'ingredient_name': 'Сыр гауда', 'quantity': 100, 'measure': 'г'},
    ]
}
```

Пока что то такое получается:

```
with open("recipes.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
     d = {i.split(" ")[0]: " ".join(i.replace("\n", "").split(" ")[1:]) for i in f} 
print(d)
```

Comment: При этом количество блюд в txt файле может быть произвольным

Comment: 1) Проставьте язык в тегах. 2) Что вы уже пытались сами сделать?

Comment: Код добавьте в вопрос, комментарий с кодом удалите. Вы можете редактировать вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно читать файл и разбирать строки используя примитивный FSM (конечный автомат):

```
ST_TITLE = 1
ST_COUNT = 2
ST_INGREDIENTS = 3

cook_book = {}
state = ST_TITLE
with open("78.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue
        if state == ST_TITLE:
            title = line
            cook_book[title] = []
            state = ST_COUNT
        elif state == ST_COUNT:
            count = int(line)
            state = ST_INGREDIENTS
        else: # if state == ST_INGREDIENTS:
            data = [x.strip() for x in line.split('|')]
            data[1] = int(data[1])
            cook_book[title].append(dict(zip(('ingredient_name', 'quantity', 'measure'), data)))
            count -= 1
            if count == 0:
                state = ST_TITLE

print(cook_book)
```